# how to use a new class method in other apps?

Tags: c#

I used this code in c++ to use a class (that I defined before)in my other Apps.

```
#include class_name ;
```

How can I define a public class that could be used in all apps?
Thanks

Comment: Read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9afc042.aspx

Comment: You need to learn about classes and namespaces.

Answer (score 3):

To access classes from external assemblies you must [add a reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to an external assembly. This will allow you to access `public` classes from the external assembly.

To specify a `class` from a `namespace` outside your current scope you must prefix the class's type specifier with its `namespace` name. To avoid this overhead, you can "include" the external `namespace` with the [`using` directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Multiple namespaces can exist within a single assembly.

---

**Assembly Fruit:**

```
namespace Common
{
    public class Strange
    {
       var mystery = new Mystery() // Won't compile, no reference to Mystery.
    }
}

namespace Fruit
{
    public class Orange
    {
    }
}
```

**Assembly Vegetables:**

*References Fruit*

```
namespace Common
{
    public class Mystery
    {
    }
}

namespace Fungi
{
    public class Mushroom
    {
    }
}

namespace Vegetables
{
    using Common;

    public Class Carrot
    {
        var strange = new Strange() // Compiles correctly.
        var mystery = new Mystery() // Compiles correctly.
        var orange = new Orange() // Won't compile, what's an Orange?
        var orange = new Fruit.Orange() // Compiles correctly.
        var mushroom = new Mushroom() // Won't compile, what's a Mushroom?
        var mushroom = new Fungi.Mushroom() // Compiles correctly.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a Class Library project, which compiles to a DLL file.

You can then add a reference to it in other projects.

Comment: @L.B: Because it isn't an application.

Comment: DLL is good if you want use the class in multiple applications, otherwise just use the using directive.

Comment: I defined and saved it but still not able to use "using class_name" and it's method

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the namespace as below and also add any references if in another project.

```
using class_namespace;
```

Comment: How and where did you define a public class?

Answer (score 0):

If the other class is `public` or `internal` (and in the same assembly if they are internal), is in the same project, and has the same namespace, then you don't need to do anything at all.  You will be able to refer to the other class by just using it's class name.

If they are in different namespaces then you can use a `using` statement (at the top of the file) to bring the other namespace into scope, or you can refer to the other class using the fully qualified name (i.e. `OuterNamespace.InnerNamespace.ClassName`) every time you use the class. (Which almost nobody ever does, everyone just uses `using` statements because they are so much more convenient.)

If the class is in another project entirely then you will need to add a reference to that class through visual studio.  If you are creating a project that is designed to be referenced by other projects then it's project type should be a "class library".

Answer (score 0):

Every class is created under a namespace

```
namespace abc{

public MyClass{
//functionality
}

}
```

To use your class on a different application,you need to import the namespace.

```
using abc;

public class usingClass{

MyClass obj = new MyClass();

}
```